# How to match only the ip and not letters

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse an error log with regex. It will give me everything I want but now I want to omit the text "client", or any text that would be in that place. All I want from between the `[]` is the ip address.

```
^\[([^]]+)\]\s*\[([^]]+)\]\s*\[([^]]+)\]\s*([A-Za-z ]*)[:]\s*([\/a-z-]*)$
```

Here is a line from the log.

```
[Mon Aug 23 15:25:35 2010] [error] [client 80.154.42.54] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmy-admin
```

Comment: Do you want just the IP?  Or the entire line, minus the text "client"?

Comment: I would say the entire line minus the text "client" and the `[]` brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^\[([^]]+)\]\s*\[([^]]+)\]\s*\[[a-zA-Z ]*([0-9.]+)\]\s*([A-Za-z ]*)[:]\s*([\/a-z-]*)$
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/uN3fO3

Matches: (Using your example data..)

```
1. `Mon Aug 23 15:25:35 2010`
2. `error`
3. `80.154.42.54`
4. `File does not exist`
5. `/var/www/phpmy-admin`
```

Comment: Thanks MElliot. Can you tell me where I am going wrong in my logic? I was under the impression that I should have been able to match just the IP with something like `[0-9.]`

Comment: If your format is always consistent (e.g. using the `[]` as edging), sweet. Otherwise, this might be a more accurate regex match for the IP address: `((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})`

Comment: @NaN - Well, you still have to match the text (client ) but then only "capture" () the IP address.  Like this: `[a-zA-Z ]+([0-9.]+)`.  Notice the parens around the `[0-9.]+`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I was under the impression that I could match anywhere in the string. In other words, skip over and not match what I don't want. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @scrowler, thanks for the pointer. It looks like my regex still isn't matching everything I want. Can you tell me what the `?:` is for plz?

Comment: @NaN the `?:` is a non-capture group, used in that example so that you capture the overall set of numbers and periods, but not each set individually